# Is it possible to use the escape codes used in shell prompts elsewhere, such as with echo?

Tags: bash, command-line, prompt, escape-characters

Example:

- When I run

  ```
  echo -e "\[\033[;33m\][\t \u (\#th) | \w]$\[\033[0m\]"
  ```

  the printed response is

  ```
  \[\][    \u (\#th) | \w]$\[\]
  ```

  where everything after the first `\[` and before the last `\]` is an orangey-brown.
- However when I set the command prompt to

  ```
  \[\033[;33m\][\t \u (\#th) | \w]$\[\033[0m\]
  ```

  the command prompt is printed as

  ```
  [21:55:17 {username} (89th) | {current directory path}]$
  ```

  were the whole command prompt is the orangy-brown.

In conclusion, my question is: Can I have a command prompt design printed (with `echo`, `cat`, `less`, etc.) as if it were the command prompt?

Comment: No, but you can replace `\u` with `${USER}`, `\w` with `${PWD}` etc. The escape sequences for changing colours work in any ANSI terminal.

Comment: Escape codes will work, because they're processed by the terminal emulator  Other things, like `\t`, `\u`, `\w` won't because they have different meanings outside of the PS1 variable. (e.g. `\t` usually means a tab, or just a backslash-escaped literal `t`. It's only in a prompt variable like PS1 that it means the current time in HH:MM:SS format)

Comment: OP asked the same question on https://superuser.com/questions/1664971/is-it-possible-to-use-the-escape-codes-used-in-shell-prompts-elseware-such-as-w.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Bash 4.4+, you can use `${var@P}`, similarly to how `${var@Q}` produces the contents of `var` quoted, see [3.5.3 Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html) in the manual, bottom of page.

```
$ printf "%s\n" "${var}" 
\[\033[00;32m\]\w\[\033[00m\]\$
$ printf "%s\n" "${var@P}"  |od -tx1z
0000000 01 1b 5b 30 30 3b 33 32 6d 02 2f 74 6d 70 01 1b  >..[00;32m./tmp..<
0000020 5b 30 30 6d 02 24 0a                             >[00m.$.<
0000027
```

or if you run the latter without `od`, you should see the current path in green.

Note that it prints `\001` and `\002` for `\[` and `\]`. Those probably aren't too useful for you. We could use a temporary variable and the string replace expansion to get rid of them:

```
$ printf -v pst "%s\n" "${var@P}" 
$ pst=${pst//[$'\001\002']}
$ printf "%s\n" "$pst" |od -tx1z
0000000 1b 5b 30 30 3b 33 32 6d 2f 74 6d 70 1b 5b 30 30  >.[00;32m/tmp.[00<
0000020 6d 24 0a 0a                                      >m$..<
0000024
```

---

In Zsh, there's `print -P`:

```
$ print -P "%F{green}%d%F{normal}%#" |od -tx1z
0000000 1b 5b 33 32 6d 2f 74 6d 70 2f 61 61 61 1b 5b 33  >.[32m/tmp/aaa.[3<
0000020 39 6d 25 0a                                      >9m%.<
```

and the parameter expansion flag `%`, so `${(%)var}` would be similar to Bash's `${var@P}` above, and you could use either `print -v othervar -P "..."` or `othervar=${(%)var}` to put the resulting string in `othervar`.

---

Note that for things like Bash's `\u` and `\w`, you could just use `$USER` and `$PWD` instead, but for something like `\#` or `\j` that might not be so easy.

Comment: In zsh, there's also the `%` parameter expansion flag (closer to bash's @P, though precedes it by decades).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I figured it had to be there, but for some reason just couldn't find it, thanks.

Comment: See also `%%` for full prompt expansion. You'd need `print -rPv othervar -- $var` for a closer equivalent.